# Computational Complexity of Marginalization

Tags: marginal-distribution, time-complexity

Suppose you have a joint probability distribution with M variables, each sampled from a set of cardinality N.  Now, suppose you want to marginalize one of the variables.  My guess right now about the computational complexity of this is O(N^(M-1)).  My thinking is that you have to go to each entry P(x,y...z) and add up all the probabilities P(x,y,....z,qi).  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

edit:
I meant that I want the whole table.  I guess the data structure that is given to you is something like a numpy array and that would be the returned type too.

Comment: Please tell us in what form the joint distribution is given and in what form the answer will be represented, because the answer cannot be derived without that.  There are $O(N)$ solutions, depending on the data structures used.

Comment: What, exactly, would this numpy array represent?  A probability mass function?  A probability distribution function?  A moment generating function?  *Etc., etc.*

Comment: @whuber It would be an M dimensional array where each entry is P(x1,x2,....xM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want a full table from (1,1,1...) to (N,N,N...N) or an algorithm for computing each point of the marginal distribution?

The naive algorithm to calculate a point on marginal distibution of $ P(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$

is just the sum of all possibilities on the margin. For example, $P(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1})= \sum_{i=1}^{N}P(x_1,...x_{n-1},x_n=i)$ by law of total probability.

This algorithm of finding a point is $O(N^k)$, where k is the number of marginalized variables. Or $O(N)$ when you need only one result.

The naive Algorithm to find the whole table is thus $O(N)*2^{(n-1)}$

I honestly am not sure if you can really go simpler

Comment: What do you mean by the "whole table" and where do you obtain a power of $2$??

Comment: @whuber I mean the table of value that contain the function value of the marginal distribution of from all possible input

Comment: If you mean the table of the *probability mass function,* then computing all those sums directly requires $M(N^{M-1}-1)$ additions to store $MN$ results.  But another common and useful way to represent a joint distribution is through its cumulative distribution function *and that already explicitly contains the marginal distributions,* meaning *no* work is needed!